How to return the right array for f(0), tail-call optimized Fibonacci?
I'm studying recursion and I'm trying to make a tail-call optimized Fibonacci which returns an array of Fibonacci numbers up to the argument passed.
The problem I am encountering is with Fibonacci of 0, which should return [0], but now returns [0, 1].


// Fibonacci recursive, tail call optimised, returns an array
function fibRecursiveTCO(n) {
  return fibonacciRecursiveTCO(n, 0, 1);
}

function fibonacciRecursiveTCO(n, a, b, result = [0, 1]) {
  if (n <= 1) {
    return result;
  }

  const next = a + b;
  result.push(next);
  return fibonacciRecursiveTCO(n - 1, b, next, result);
}

console.log(fibRecursiveTCO(0)); // expected [0], returns [0, 1] instead
console.log(fibRecursiveTCO(1)); // [0, 1]
console.log(fibRecursiveTCO(19)); // Array(20) [0, 1, ..., 4181]




After some rubber ducking, the working solution was to change result = [0, 1] to  result = [0, 1].slice(0, n + 1)

First of all, if you are using recursion, then reap its benefits. In our case, you have a composite problem, i.e., get the first 19 Fibonacci numbers and you should always decompose your problem to similar, but simpler sub-problems. So, what the result should be for F(19)? The result should be F(17) + F(18) and so on backwards.
So let's automate this decomposing of the problem until we reach the trivial case of F(1), which is 1 and for which you want a result of [0, 1]. So the caller of fibonacciRecursiveTCO(n - 1) will get the Fibonacci numbers up to F(n - 1), so when the function returns, you have both F(n - 2) and F(n - 1) at your disposal (provided that n >= 2, because otherwise you have a trivial case) and you can add the two and concat the result to your previous result.
Now that we handled the more complex cases properly, decomposing the problem into sub-problems and building back the result from the trivial towards the more complex, let's turn our focus to the trivial cases.
For the sake of simplicity the implementation I have given assumes that n will be a natural number and completely ignores the possibility of negative, non-discrete or non-numeric inputs. In a professional environment you will need to contemplate on what to do in such cases too, but here we deal only with natural numbers.
We have two trivial cases for natural numbers. Either you have n being 0 or 1. In both cases we return result, that is, the default. Yet, we face the problem of needing two separate defaults, [0] being the default when n is 0 and [0, 1] being the default when n is 1. So, which of the two should be the default default? Well, since all inputs will boil down to n being 1's default, except for the exceptional case when n was 0, the default default is chosen to be [0, 1].
However, then something will need to know that for n being 0, the default needs to be [0]. I handled this in fibRecursiveTCO, which will specify what the default result is if n was 0, but you might want to make sure that fibonacciRecursiveTCO is unreachable apart from fibRecursiveTCO so the defaults will be guaranteed to be handled properly. For that purpose you could create a class and make sure that fibRecursiveTCO is public and fibonacciRecursiveTCO is private. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_properties


// Fibonacci recursive, tail call optimised, returns an array
function fibRecursiveTCO(n) {
  return n ? fibonacciRecursiveTCO(n) : fibonacciRecursiveTCO(n, [0]);
}

function fibonacciRecursiveTCO(n, result = [0, 1]) {
  if (n <= 1) {
      return result;
  }
  let previous = fibonacciRecursiveTCO(n - 1, result);
  return previous.concat(previous[previous.length - 2] + previous[previous.length - 1]);
}

console.log(fibRecursiveTCO(0)); // expected [0], returns [0, 1] instead
console.log(fibRecursiveTCO(1)); // [0, 1]
console.log(fibRecursiveTCO(19)); // Array(20) [0, 1, ..., 4181]




This Loop and Recur interface, originally introduced in this Q&A, is capable of expressing many tail recursive functions without having to write auxiliary helpers or lean on other imperative constructs.
In this first example we compute the 100,000th term in about 100 milliseconds. In the second example we will show how to modify the function to compute a list of terms instead -


const fib = x =>
  Loop(                             // <- loop
    (n, a, b) =>                    // <- vars {n}, {a}, and {b}
      n <= 0n                       // <- exit condition
        ? String(a)                 // <- base case
        : Recur(n - 1n, b, a + b),  // <- recursive case
    BigInt(x),                      // <- init {n}
    0n,                             // <- init {a}
    1n,                             // <- init {b}
  )
  
function Loop(f, ...init) {
  let r = f(...init)          // <- apply f for initial result
  while (r instanceof Recur)  // <- if result is Recur
    r = f(...r)               // <- apply f again
  return r                    // <- return non-Recur result
}

function Recur(...v) {
  return Object.create(                                // <- simple object
    Recur.prototype,                                   // <- prototype
    { [Symbol.iterator]: { value: _ => v.values() } }, // <- values
  )
}

console.time("fib(100000)")
document.body.textContent = fib(100000)
console.timeEnd("fib(100000)")
body { overflow-wrap: anywhere; }
.as-console-row:after { min-width: 150px; }



Now we modify to return a list instead of a single number -


const fibs = x =>
  Loop(
    (n, a, b, r) =>           // <- additional var, {r}
      n <= 0n
        ? r                   // <- return result
        : Recur(
            n - 1n,
            b,
            a + b,
            (r.push(a), r),   // <- append {a} to result
          ),
    BigInt(x),
    0n,
    1n,
    [0n],                     // <- init result, {r}
  )
  
function Loop(f, ...init) {
  let r = f(...init)
  while (r instanceof Recur)
    r = f(...r)
  return r
}

function Recur(...v) {
  return Object.create(
    Recur.prototype,
    { [Symbol.iterator]: { value: _ => v.values() } },
  )
}

console.time("fibs(1000)")
const result = fibs(1000)             // <- result is array
console.timeEnd("fibs(1000)")
document.body.textContent = result.join(", ")
body { overflow-wrap: anywhere; }
.as-console-row:after { min-width: 150px; }



Because of the way Loop works, we could also initialize the loop parameters using default values. I find this to be an improvement on readability when parameter count is higher -
const fibs = x =>
  Loop(
    ( n = BigInt(x),         // <- init {n}
      a = 0n,                // <- init {a}
      b = 1n,                // <- init {b}
      r = [0n]               // <- init {r}
    ) =>
      n <= 0n
        ? r
        : Recur(
            n - 1n,          // <- next {n}
            b,               // <- next {a}
            a + b,           // <- next {b}
            (r.push(a), r),  // <- next {r}
          )
  )

As requested, here is a typescript version. It's not perfect as it does not prevent recur with types differing from the loop signature -
type Loop<T> =
  | { type: "done"; value: T }
  | { type: "recur"; values: any[] }

function done<T>(value: T): Loop<T>  {
  return { type: "done", value }
}

function recur(...values: any[]): Loop<unknown> {
  return { type: "recur", values }
}

function loop<T>(f: (...args: any[]) => Loop<T>): T {
  let r: Loop<T> = f()
  while (r.type == "recur")
    r = f(...r.values)
  return r.value // discriminate union: {done} type inferred here
}

const fib = (x: number) =>
  loop(
    ( n = BigInt(x),
      a = 0n,
      b = 1n,
    ) =>
      n <= 0n
        ? done(String(a))
        : recur(n - 1n, b, a + b)
  )

console.time("fib(100000)")
console.log(fib(100000))
console.timeEnd("fib(100000)")

A different interface would be required to enforce any loop output matches the input. Consider something like -
const fib = x =>
  loop(controller => (n = x, a = 0, b = 1) =>
    n <= 0
      ? controller.done(a)
      : controller.recur(n - 1, b, a + b))

Where the controller's type could be inferred and expected to match the lambda's type. Implementation of loop is similar but typing that is a bit beyond my current typescript skill level.

Very nice as always!  Question 1:  What is the point of constructor: { value: Recur },?  My from-memory copy of an earlier version of this skips that.   Does it solve a problem that I simply haven't run across?

Question 2: A friend who'd seen this asked how to replicate it in Typescript.  I'm not much of a TS user.  Are you?  Have you tried it in TS?

Hi Scott ^^ I don't think your gist will work because the arrow functions don't get a prototype. To answer your question though, you should be able to skip the constructor property in this case. It is needed when doing prototypal inheritance, a phrase you do not hear much nowadays! I cleaned them up and I took a shot at the TS implemetation for you. I hope it helps

Thanks.  That gist does work for the cases I've tried.  Except for layout, it looks identical to the current version above.  I'll share the TS with that friend in case he's still looking.  I certainly understand prototypal inheritance; I just didn't see where it would needed when using this Loop-Recur implementation.  Again, thank you!

I wonder what's happening here. If you copy/paste that Recur implementation into your browser console and attempt creating a value, Recur(1), I am seeing a TypeError, Object prototype may only be an Object or null. This matches my expectation of const F = () => {} and  F.prototype === undefined.

I was fooled by an ancient REPL!  That is a very old version of Babel.  Obviously it needs to be updated.  (It was written before es6 was ubiquitous, and it's converting arrow functions into function expressions.  That's why it works.)  But I swear I've used this in other environments, too, but probably that from-memory bit fooled me!  Thank you for the help!

I fixed the gist to replace that with a function expression.  Thank you for the heads-up!

After playing with this for a while, I found an answer that returns all the expected results:


function fibRecursiveTCO(n) {
  return fibonacciRecursiveTCO(n, 0, 1);
}

function fibonacciRecursiveTCO(n, a, b, result = [0, 1].slice(0, n + 1)) {
  if (n <= 1) {
    return result;
  }

  const next = a + b;
  result.push(next);
  return fibonacciRecursiveTCO(n - 1, b, next, result);
}

console.log(fibRecursiveTCO(0)); // [0]
console.log(fibRecursiveTCO(1)); // [0, 1]
console.log(fibRecursiveTCO(19)); // Array(20) [0, 1, ..., 4181]




So, the base case has to be [0,1] because you always need two numbers to add, but for fib(0) you only want to return the first one. Since the result of fib(n) always has n+1 numbers, you can just always just do if (n <= 1) return result.slice(0, n+1) in your base case.

I would handle the [0] case without calling the recursion, and use [0, 1] as the base result. In addition, moving forwards allow me to use the numbers in the result array to compute the next values.


function fibs(nth) {
  if (nth === 0) return [0];

  const fibonacciRecursiveTCO = (n, result) => { 
    if (n > nth) return result;

    return fibonacciRecursiveTCO(
      n + 1, 
      [...result, result.at(-2) + result.at(-1)]
    );
  }
  
  return fibonacciRecursiveTCO(2, [0, 1]);
}



console.log(fibs(0)); // [0]
console.log(fibs(1)); // [0, 1]
console.log(fibs(19));
console.time("fibs(1000)")
fibs(1000)
console.timeEnd("fibs(1000)")



To optimize the time, we can avoid recreating the results array using array spread, and use the Array.push() instead:


function fibs(nth) {
  if (nth === 0) return [0];

  const fibonacciRecursiveTCO = (n, result) => { 
    if (n > nth) return result;

    return fibonacciRecursiveTCO(
      n + 1, 
      (result.push(result.at(-2) + result.at(-1)), result)
    );
  }
  
  return fibonacciRecursiveTCO(2, [0, 1]);
}


console.time("fibs(1000)");
const results = fibs(1000);
console.timeEnd("fibs(1000)");
document.body.textContent = results.join(", ")



